# Angular routing is not working on hard refresh

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

if i visit URL https://localhost:4200/user, on this page i have link to /edit-email page and if i click In result I am able to see view as I have done code. but if i directly enter  https://localhost:4200/user/edit-email on browser or i refresh hard. in result I am not getting any view. in console i can see error. *Refused to apply style from '**https://localhost:4200/user/styles.css**' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.*

I don`t know, i am getting /user while loading styles

Below here is my user.routing file code.

```
onst routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:UserComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGaurd,RoleGaurd],
    children:[
      {
        path:'',
        component:DashboardComponent,
        pathMatch:'full'
      },
      {
        path:'edit-email',
        component:EditEmailComponent,
        pathMatch:'full'
      }
    ],
    data:{
      'role':'user'
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: What is href of base tag in index html?

Comment: <base href="./"/> i also tried with direct https://localhost:4200

Comment: Use "/" - it's root of your application.

Comment: serving issue.  ..

Comment: I think that the MIME type for CSS files is normally 'text/css'. Does it come in that way when you navigate to /user? What does your angular.json look like? Are you running the app via 'ng serve'?

Comment: @Taras worked with /, Thanks